# Laravel query: multiple conditions in where clause but 1 condition requires comparison operator

Tags: php, laravel, where-clause

I have been trying to get a Laravel select query to work which requires multiple AND conditions. I understand you could normally do this:

```
$myArray = array('column_one' => 1, 'column_two' => 2);

DB::('mytable')->select('mycolumn')->where($myArray)->get();
```

How do you do this with one where statement when a comparison operator is required?

Something like:

```
DB::('mytable')->select('mycolumn')->where('column_one', 1)->where('column_two' '<', 10000)->get();
```

but with only one where statement instead of chaining them. I searched the Laravel docs and could not find this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you are on 5.2 and a up to date version of it you can pass an array of arrays with the operator in them.

From the 5.2 docs:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where([
    ['status','1'],
    ['subscribed','<>','1'],
])->get();
```

If you have a operator you want to use, it would be the second element of the array which has 3 elements. In the example above `['subscribed', '<>', '1']`, the `'<>'` is the operator.

[Laravel 5.2 - Query Builder - Wheres](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: you can use `orWhere` also, something like this `    `DB::('mytable')->select('mycolumn')->where('column_one', 1)->orWhere('column_two' '<', 10000)->get();`

Comment: @imrealashu OP stated 'AND' operator, and the question is how to do it with one call to `where()`.

Comment: yeah i know, i commented on your answer instead of qustion, and I was just pointing that `orWhere` can also be used instead of two `where()`

Comment: @imrealashu...I know about orWhere and it serves no purpose for me. Can you please remove your comment? Everyone who uses Laravel knows about orWhere

Comment: @imrealashu...I didn't even see your first comment...this is most definitely not what I want and would return incorrect data for my project. Please remove all of your comments since they are obfuscating the good responses made by others users.

Comment: I was just thinking to myself ... you know what this answer is missing ?   unrelated comments    :)

Comment: @lagbox...tried this and still was getting an error. Thanks for the answer but due to time constraints I just used DB::raw() which worked

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob no prob, sorry it didn't work out. Note for future posts, always include the Laravel version, there are many.

Comment: OK...will do. Thanks!